# Import Issue with Matplotlib and Pyplot (Python / Tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter, python-import

I am having an issue where I cannot call the 'pyplot' element of 'matplotlib'. From the code below you can see I've had to add a "TkAgg" for the mattplotlib element to work, which is a common issue.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
```

However, now I cannot add the '.pyplot' to the import. I've tried the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.use("TkAgg")
```

But this gives me the error:

> AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'use'

How can I get around this as my code requires pyplot to function, but I cannot work out how to import it while still having to use ".use("TkAgg").

I am running Python 3.6.2 and I am using Tkinter to develop my program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are two entirely different things. You import `matplotlib` to be able to set the backend. Then you need to still import `pyplot` to be able to use it afterwards.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# ... rest of code
```

Comment: Okay great thank you @importanceofbeingernest that's solved that issue. However I am now getting an error "TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars"

Comment: Sure, you may get any error from some code you do not share here and there is no way of helping you with unknown code.

Comment: I know, I wasn't sure if it was relevant to this.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the use() function, this must be done before importing matplotlib.pyplot. Calling use() after pyplot has been imported will have no effect.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

check with :

```
matplotlib.get_backend()
```